# bash substitutions don't appear to work when matching newline characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have an executable file called `test.script` containing this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=${1//$'\n'/}
output=${temp//$'\r'/}
printf "$output" > output.txt
```

When I run

```
sudo ./test.script "^\r\r\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n\r\n\rHello World\n\n\r\r\r\n\n\r\r\r$"
```

in the same directory as test.script, I expect to end up with an output.txt looking like this:

```
^Hello World$
```

but when I take a look I instead see this:

```
^









Hello World








$
```

Clearly I have a misunderstanding about regex in bash.

Please explain to me what I am missing, then show me how to write the bash so that all newline characters are removed from the string before said string is written to a file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling your script with `sudo`?

Comment: If I don't use sudo, then I get a permission denied error on the line with `printf "$output" > output.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "fix" your script like this (although I must say this isn't typical usage of `printf`):

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=${1//'\n'/}
output=${temp//'\r'/}
printf "$output"
```

The argument to your script `$1` doesn't contain real newlines or carriage returns, which is what `$'\n'` and `$'\r'` are for. Instead, it looks like you just want to remove the literal strings `'\n'` and `'\r'`.

To elaborate on my point about `printf`, normally two (or more) arguments are passed: the format specifier and the variables that are to be inserted. For example, to print a single string you would use something like `printf '%s' "$output"`. In your script, the variable `$output` is being treated as the format specifer; you're relying on `printf` to expand your  `\n` and `\r` into newlines and carriage returns.

You're not actually using regular expressions here by the way; the syntax `${var//match/replace}` is a substring replacement, where `//` means that all occurrences of the substring `match` in `$var` are replaced. As you haven't specified anything to replace the substring with, the substring is replaced with nothing (i.e. removed).

Comment: Alternatively, your script would work if called like `sudo ./test.script $'^\r\r\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n\r\n\rHello World\n\n\r\r\r\n\n\r\r\r$'`.

Comment: Is there a way I could write the script so all of the substitutions (deletions in this case) could be specified in one line?

Comment: Yeah you could use `output=$(sed 's/\\[nr]//g' <<<"$1")` to remove a `\ ` followed by `n` or `r`. The disadvantage of this approach is this you have to call an external command to do something that bash is capable of by itself but it does save you a line.